# V-model on div tag component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

There's an issue when using `v-model` to `div` tags. Apparently, `div` tags doesn't allow `v-model` and I've decided to create my comment section as a component. I needed to assign this `div` text area as is because of UI/UX reasons. `textarea`, `input`, etc tags, as to my knowledge, these tags are not compatible with `contenteditable="true"`; I need to expand the height of the input field as a user types in their comments. Below is the vue component that I imported in my parent view.

```
<!-- CommentSection.vue -->
<template>
    <div id="chatId" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Leave a message" class="overflow-hidden block mx-4 text-left p-2.5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-white rounded-2xl border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500"/>
</template>

<style>
#chatId[contenteditable="true"]:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content: attr(placeholder)
}
</style>
```

On my view file, I imported it and used `v-model` into it, just like this.

```
<!--MainPage.vue-->
<template>
...
...
     <CommentSection v-model="comment"/>
     <button @click="submitPost()"> Submit </button>
...
...
...
</template>
<script>
import CommentSection from '@/components/CommentSection.vue'

export default{
 name: 'MainPage',
      data(){
          return{
            comment: '',
          }
      },
      components: { CommentSection },
      methods:{
          submitPost(){
             console.log(this.comment);
          },
      },
}
</script>
```

However, when I check my console, it gives me the value "null" or just nothing. Is there's a way to fix this? Or is it the way I implemented it that causes the problem.

EDIT: Here's the running code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-flower-sthf2t?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue).

Comment: `Is there's a way to fix this?` ... fix what? your `MainPage` data sets `comment` to `""` ... and nowhere in the code is there any reason why `comment` would ever change - you also mention `the error` ... what error? are you seeing an error in the console?

Comment: Sorry, there's no error, however, it doesn't return the value that was inputted in the ```div``` textarea. I added the link to the code.

Comment: how is the content of "that div" at all "linked" to `comment`? your `CommentSection`  component doesn't have any script at all, so I can't see how you think `v-model="comment"` will do anything

Comment: in the coedsandbox ... `v-model="comment"` in App, and the only prop in HelloWorld is `msg` ... I think you need to read how vue components work again

Comment: I didn't add any script in my ```CommentSection``` component. All I needed was to maintain the UX of that ```div``` text area and use v-model into it as I imported it to my parent view.

Comment: How do you expect to bind comment to the content of the div?

Comment: see, `v-model` works "out of the box" for input/textarea - but not for your own components

Comment: Exactly, ```v-model``` doesn't work with ```div``` tags. Although I tried using ```document.getElementById("chatId").value``` it doesn't even return anything. I really need to implement ```contenteditable="true"``` to give users a good UX. But, it seems that it's not achievable after all.

Comment: it is - as long as you write "code" ... add `@blur="change" :text="modelValue"` to the div ... add `modelValue` to the `props` and a method like `change(e) { this.$emit("update:modelValue", e.target.textContent); }` - that'll get you going+

Comment: Alright, I'll make the most out of it. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-joana-p0yqcn?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: The div contenteditable does have the `input` event. So you can listen to it instead of `blur`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved your problem and the code is as follows. I hope I have helped

By adding @ to the div tag, we can see the changes in the content of the tag in the change method. And in that method, use emit$ to share its value with other components

```
<!-- CommentSection.vue -->
<template>
    <div id="chatId" @input="chanage" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Leave a message" class="overflow-hidden block mx-4 text-left p-2.5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-white rounded-2xl border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    chanage (e) {
      this.$emit('value-div', e.target.textContent)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#chatId[contenteditable="true"]:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content: attr(placeholder)
}
</style>
```

And here we have the props created by $emit, whose value we initialize in the comment variable. Actually, it has a function similar to v-model.

```
<!--MainPage.vue-->
<template>
...
...
     <CommentSection @value-div="(value)=>comment = value"/>
     <button @click="submitPost()"> Submit </button>
...
...
...
</template>
<script>
import CommentSection from '@/components/CommentSection.vue'

export default{
 name: 'MainPage',
      data(){
          return{
            comment: '',
          }
      },
      components: { CommentSection },
      methods:{
          submitPost(){
             console.log(this.comment);
          },
      },
}
</script>
```

Comment: While the code might work (can't validate so erring on caution), how does this help? What was the issue? Code only answers, while "answer the question" don't really help learn as to the how. Please make sure you add explanations and reasons

Comment: @CanO'Spam

Yes, you are right, I edited my answer and added explanations